# Gulp 4 Migration Errors (Did you forget to signal async completion?)

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-automation

I have a gulp 3 file which I am trying to upgrade to gulp 4. When I do so some of the tasks work others dont. The three errors that i am getting are as follows:

clean-styles:

```
gulp.task('clean-styles', function (done) {
    var files = config.temp + '**/*.css';
    clean(files, done);
});

[23:47:05] The following tasks did not complete: clean-styles 
[23:47:05] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

scss-watcher:

```
gulp.task('scss-watcher', function () {
    gulp.watch([config.scss], ['styles']);
});

[23:51:27] 'scss-watcher' errored after 2.46 ms
[23:51:27] Error: watching ./src/client/styles/styles.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
```

styles: (This will work if i remove the clean-styles series)

```
gulp.task('styles', gulp.series('clean-styles', function () {
log('Compiling SCSS --> CSS');

return gulp
    .src(config.scss)
    .pipe($.scss())
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%'] }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
}));

[23:52:42] The following tasks did not complete: styles, clean-styles
[23:52:42] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

vet: (Works)

```
gulp.task('vet', function () {
    log('Analyzing source with ESLint');
    return gulp
        .src(config.js)
        .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.print()))
        .pipe($.eslint())
        .pipe($.eslint.format())
        .pipe($.eslint.failOnError());
});
```

functions:

```
function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
    del(path, done);
}

function log(msg) {
    if (typeof(msg) === 'object') {
        for (var item in msg) {
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg));
    }
}
```

I have to be missing something. Can anyone fill me in on what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**clean-styles**

[`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) doesn't take a callback function. It returns a `Promise` that you have to return in your task:

```
function clean(path) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
    return del(path);
}
gulp.task('clean-styles', function () {
    var files = config.temp + '**/*.css';
    return clean(files);
});
```

**scss-watcher**

`gulp.watch()` doesn't support arrays of task names anymore. You have to pass it a function, `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()`:

```
gulp.task('scss-watcher', function () {
    gulp.watch([config.scss], gulp.series('styles'));
});
```

**styles**

Should work with the changes to `clean-styles` above.

Comment: Thank you can i ask 1 more question. I get the following errors when compiling typescript. error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'., error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'., error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'., error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'. error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'. error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning. Yet it still compiles. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: That isn't really related to your original question of migrating to Gulp 4. You should open a new question and include the error message and the relevant portions of your Gulpfile (or whatever you use to compile TypeScript files). Might be good to include a minimal TypeScript file as well with which the error can be reproduced.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Does this mean Gulp 4 documentation at readme.io is incorrect: https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpwatchglob-opts-fn ? It says first argument can be array of globs: "A single glob or array of globs that indicate which files to watch for changes."

Comment: @revelt Array of globs != array of tasks. Two different things.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Good point. I was using globs myself and didn't pay attention to "tasks" part. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Friends, this is workaround this issue:

We need to call the callback functions(Task and Anonimous

```
function electronTask(callbackA)
{
    return gulp.series(myFirstTask, mySeccondTask, (callbackB) =>
    {
        callbackA();
        callbackB();
    });

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the last to parens `()` because the series doesn't return a function to be called. (AFAIK)